# Angular Material 2 Spinner on boot

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-material2

I'm new on Angular 2. I use the [`angular-cli`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to create an app.

I need to use the [Progress Spinner component](https://material.angular.io/components/component/progress-spinner) on the startup of the project, I'm searching about how to use it on the boot of the project, but I don't find anything about it. I know that is possible because I see many projects that have used this, [this is an example](http://fuse-angular-material.withinpixels.com/?v=1.4.5). Can you help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is very easy to implement using a SVG graphic and this:

```
<div id="loader"><img src="assets/img/loader-preview.svg" alt="loading"></div>
```

on the main app (index.html for me):

```
<body>
<base href='/'>
<my-app>
    <div id="loader"><img src="assets/img/loader-preview.svg" alt="loading"></div>
</my-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this

```
@Component({
    selector: 'spinner',
    template: `<div *ngIf="show">
                    <span><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" [ngStyle]="{'font-size': size+'px'}" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
               </div>
    `
})
export class SpinnerComponent {
    @Input() size: number = 50;
    @Input() show: boolean;

}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/sS1WXgZ62aR1NgEipDGl?p=info)**

Comment: In case someone looking for Angular 2 or 4 Spinner and How it works then I recommend to read this great article I highly recommend and I implemented successfully and it works                                           
           
http://codetunnel.io/how-to-do-loading-spinners-the-angular-2/